# AlertDialog.Builder message not seen in Espresso View Hierarchy

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have an activity that contains an AlertDialog that pops up on button press. I want to check if the message of this is correct with what I expect. Espresso sees the AlertDialog title but not the message.

[Screenshot of the message text I want to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbdHD.png)

Here's my code:

```
@Test
public void firstInningsInterruption1Test1() {
    onView(withText("First Innings")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText("First Innings")).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_number_overs_edit_text)).perform(scrollTo(),clearText(), typeText("20"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_which_over_interruption_1_et)).perform(scrollTo(),clearText(), typeText("12"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_total_interruption_1_et)).perform(scrollTo(),clearText(), typeText("85"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_wickets_lost_interruption_1_et)).perform(scrollTo(),clearText(), typeText("2"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_overs_remaining_interruption_1_et)).perform(scrollTo(),clearText(), typeText("3"),closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_team1_final_total_et)).perform(clearText(), typeText("120"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_team2_overs_et)).perform(clearText(), typeText("15"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.first_innings_calc_button)).perform(click());
    onView(withText("Target")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText("Team 2 needs 128 runs to win.")).check(matches(isDisplayed())); //<--- this is what i need to find
    pauseTestFor(500);

}
```

Error Message:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Team 2 needs 128 runs to win."

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1026, height=567, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=471, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=48.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909295, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=471, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->FitWindowsFrameLayout{id=2131755116, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=471, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=471, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->AlertDialogLayout{id=2131755098, res-name=parentPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=471, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+------>LinearLayout{id=2131755107, res-name=topPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=159, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------->LinearLayout{id=2131755108, res-name=title_template, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=135, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-------->AppCompatImageView{id=16908294, res-name=icon, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->DialogTitle{id=2131755109, res-name=alertTitle, visibility=VISIBLE, width=786, height=81, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=72.0, y=54.0, text=Target, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->Space{id=2131755110, res-name=titleDividerNoCustom, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=135.0}
|
+------>FrameLayout{id=2131755099, res-name=contentPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=159.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->NestedScrollView{id=2131755101, res-name=scrollView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=122, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=122, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+--------->Space{id=2131755102, res-name=textSpacerNoTitle, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatTextView{id=16908299, res-name=message, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=122, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=
Team 2 needs 128 runs to win., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+--------->Space{id=2131755103, res-name=textSpacerNoButtons, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+------>FrameLayout{id=2131755105, res-name=customPanel, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->FrameLayout{id=2131755106, res-name=custom, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+------>ScrollView{id=2131755096, res-name=buttonPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=303.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->ButtonBarLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=930, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+-------->AppCompatButton{id=16908315, res-name=button3, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-------->Space{id=2131755097, res-name=spacer, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=666, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=36.0, y=156.0}
|
+-------->AppCompatButton{id=16908314, res-name=button2, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-------->AppCompatButton{id=16908313, res-name=button1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=192, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=702.0, y=12.0, text=OK, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131755117, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1566)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.sportsoutclass.outclassdl.ApplicationTest.firstInningsInterruption1Test1(ApplicationTest.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```

Comment: have you tried testing for the string resource and not typing the string again? cause i just tried it in a testproject and there it works perfectly